# MYSQL Returns FAIL Always

Tags: c++, mysql

This piece of code in C++ queries a MYSQL online database.  It seems that it always returns 0.  Even when I know the answer should be 1 PASS.  I'm not getting an errors when it runs.

```
    if ( bShowTCP )
    {
      printf("\n -------------------- // -------------------- ");
      printf("\n TCP Header:");

      int *addressValue = new int();
      char *address = LIP; 
      inet_pton(AF_INET, address, addressValue);
      if (ip_header->source_ip == *addressValue)
      {
         printf("\n   Source      IP: %s", "0.0.0.0");
         printf("\n   Destination IP: %s", ipDest);
      }
      else
      {
         printf("\n   Source      IP: %s", ipSrc);
         printf("\n   Destination IP: %s", ipDest);
         (mysql_real_connect
         (conn,"<hostname>","<db>","<user>","<pass>",0,NULL,0) !=0);
         (mysql_query(conn,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblURLIP WHERE IP = 'ipSrc' And            IPStatus = '1' And IPMax = '0'"));
         my_ulonglong i = 0;
         res_set = mysql_store_result(conn);
         my_ulonglong numrows = mysql_num_rows(res_set);
         LEGIT = mysql_fetch_row(res_set);
         if (atoi(LEGIT[i]) == 1)
         {
           printf("\n PASS: %s\n",LEGIT[i]);
           mysql_free_result(res_set);
         }
         else
         {
           printf("\n FAIL! %s\n",LEGIT[i]);
           mysql_free_result(res_set);
         }             
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no variables being passed to your MySQL query -- the `WHERE IP = 'ipSrc'` is literally searching for rows where `IP` has the value `"ipSrc"`, not ones where it's equal to the value of the string variable called `ipSrc`. You will need to either embed the value of `ipSrc` into a string using a function like `sprintf()`, or use a prepared statement and bind `ipSrc` to a placeholder variable.

Comment: This printingout an IP  printf("\n   Source      IP: %s", ipSrc); How can I pass this to a string using sprintf() or a prepared statement.  Im kinda new at this. Thanks.

Comment: Like this?   char n;        n=sprintf(ipSrc,0);

Comment: I have this earier in the code.  Does it help?                      memset( ipSrc, 0x00, sizeof(ipSrc) );
memset( ipDest, 0x00, sizeof(ipDest) );
translate_ip(ip_header->source_ip, ipSrc);
translate_ip(ip_header->destination_ip, ipDest);             char     ipSrc[20]

Comment: No, you're grasping at straws now. None of the code you've posted in these comments would have any useful effect.

Comment: So where does printf() getting the value to display the IP